# Apache Ray Automatical Cluster Setup for a Private Cluster

Tags: configuration, installation, cluster-computing, ray

I successfully setup a mini Ray cluster (1 head + 1 worker, each with 4 CPU cores) manually. However, I failed to set up it automatically using the Apache Ray autoscaler. The head node starts correctly while the worker node never joins the cluster. Below is my YAML configuration for the autoscaler. Is there anything I did wrong?

```
cluster_name: my_ray_cluster

min_workers: 8
initial_workers: 8
max_workers: 8

provider:
    type: local
    head_ip: 10.148.186.178
    worker_ips: [10.148.186.18]

auth:
    ssh_user: USER_NAME
    ssh_private_key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Files or directories to copy to the head and worker nodes. 
file_mounts: {
#    "/path1/on/remote/machine": "/path1/on/local/machine",
#    "/path2/on/remote/machine": "/path2/on/local/machine",
}

head_setup_commands: 
    - pip3 install ray[debug,dashboard]
setup_commands:
    - pip3 install ray[debug,dashboard]

# Command to start ray on the head node. You don't need to change this.
head_start_ray_commands:
    - ray stop
    - ray start --head --redis-port=6379

worker_start_ray_commands:
    - ray stop
    - ray start --address=10.148.186.178:6379
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am facing the same  issue on the private cluster!